# How to check if a polynomial regression has any predictive value?

Tags: predictive-models, prediction, predictor, polynomial

After fitting the polynomial data to a given curve, how can I check which of the many curves has the most predictive value ?

Comment: They will all have *some* predictive value.

Comment: So, I think I asked. How to maximize the predictive value. Could you gently change that for me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same way as for any model: by using a holdout sample, and comparing the polynomial fits to a simple benchmark.

Note that polynomials are notoriously poor at the boundary of the training sample because of high variance there, and that [splines](/questions/tagged/splines) are usually a better way to model nonlinearities.

Comment: Could you kindly point me a good example on the internet ?

Comment: I very much recommend Frank Harrell's *Regression Modeling Strategies*. I don't know anything on the internet, sorry.